# MVVMCross multiple ViewModels and Views per Window

Tags: c#, mvvm, wpf

I may not being fully understanding MVVM or how MVVMCross works, but my understanding of views is that they are components of a window rather than the window itself.

When you start up MVVMCross in C# WPF you specify the ViewModel which is ok, but this only relates to one view (from what I can gather). For my idea I would have an application window which gathers multiple views and places them within one window.

With MVVMCross do you write one ViewModel and populate that with a load of views? As this would mean writing duplicate code if I wanted to use the same view in another window. Or do you nest the start up ViewModel with other ViewModels?

Essentially, how do you have more than one ViewModel per Window?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I did something similar in WPF but with caliburn micro instead. I registered all the viewmodels with my DI framework and then fetched them all and displayed them.

Decoupled and nice abstraction

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/FreePIE/blob/master/FreePIE.GUI/Shells/MainShellViewModel.cs#L43

Comment: Thanks Anders, is MVVM pattern surpose to work like this or are  views in MVVM actually windows?

Comment: A view can be a part of a window or an entire window.